# angular ng-sortable how to disable drag and drop inside one draggable area

Tags: angularjs, ng-sortable

I have two tables with items. I want to be able to drag and drop items between table but not inside the same table.

How to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I found that we apply sortableOptions to ng-sortable element. We can use callback accept: function(sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope)

I receive a whole object in sourceItemHandleScope and I receive a lot of events when I started to move item. I can not figure out how to understand that I moved item from one ng-sortable area to another

Answer (score 2):

Inside your sortOptions write this accept function:

```
 //restrict move within table. move only across table.
    accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope, destItemScope) {

            console.log("sourceItemHandleScope: ", sourceItemHandleScope);
            console.log("destSortableScope: ", destSortableScope);
            console.log("destItemScope: ", destItemScope);

            return sourceItemHandleScope.itemScope.sortableScope.$parent.$id != destSortableScope.$parent.$id;


    },
```

I have used console.log to view the scopes and see how to achieve it, you can delete them.

Comment: My issue was the opposite, moving objects only within a list, and restrict accross lists. I just changed the `!=` for `==` and worked fine. Thanks!